# Installing scipy for python 2.7

Tags: python, installation, scipy, python-2.7

I cannot seem to get SciPy working for Python 2.7 on a 32 bit Windows XP platform. I'd rather not build my own copy. Does anyone know where I could find a installer for it? I tried this [site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/), but it didn't work.

Comment: I did fing the version yo require in the same link you were refering to (http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy). Tried this one and worked: scipy-0.17.0-cp27-none-win32.whl

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Download it from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/files/scipy/0.9.0rc5/scipy-0.9.0rc5-win32-superpack-python2.7.exe/download).

I'm not sure about that site you referred to, but I always start at: http://www.scipy.org

Comment: lol, I am not sure how I missed that. Brain must be gone to mush from coding. I owe you a beer

Comment: @Richard Yeah, I'm not sure how you missed it either!!  ;-)  I don't drink beer, but I would appreciate an accept in lieu!!!!  ;-)

Comment: I was fooled too. sourceforge.net seems to suggest the latest release and in my case it suggested the latest python 2.6 release rather than the latest 2.7 release I was looking for.

Comment: tried many other sources that would not build on win32. This worked.

Answer (score 9):

for future googlers a potential solution is to install the latest version of scipy that supports `python2.7` which is `0.16` (I am not sure that it is the last but it is surely among the latest):

```
pip install scipy==0.16
```

worked for me.

Comment: From browsing https://pypi.org/project/scipy/#history it seems the final release to support Python 2.x was `scipy==1.2.2`, as its the last to list Python::2 support

Answer (score 2):

Try:

sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy python-matplotlib ipython ipython-notebook python-pandas python-sympy python-nose

It works on my Banana Pi single board computer.

Answer (score 0):

Install miniconda
 Install python 2.7.13 or whatever the latest version of 2.x by running
`conda install python=2.7.13`
switch to python 2.x in your IDE (in my case pyzo) from the miniconda directory
`conda install scipy`
and it worked for me. regular `pip install scipy` didnt work for 2.x

Answer (score 0):

You can install scikit-image using "pip install -U scikit-image" and scipy will be automatically installed. You can even install just scipy using "pip install scipy"